# Uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to figure out if $f_n=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. It converges pointwise to $0$, but to show it converges uniformly I need to have an $n$ such that $\left|\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

This does not seem possible as I can't seem to bound it by something not depending on $x$ but I can't seem to find a counterexample. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assume $n \geq 2.$ Then, $0 \leq f_n(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x^{2n} + nx^{2n-2} + 1 + h_n(x)} \leq \dfrac{x^2}{x^{2n} + nx^{2n-2} + 1}=\dfrac{1}{x^{2n-2}+nx^{2n-4} + 1};$ if $|x| \geq 1,$ the last expression is $\leq \dfrac{1}{n};$ on the interval, $[-1,1]$ we have $f_n(x)$ is decreasing (for $x$ fixed and $n$ variable) to $0,$ hence Dini's theorem gives that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,1].$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

By binomial theorem:

$$(1+x^2)^n > nx^2 \implies \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n} < \ldots $$

Comment: I tried to use it, but didn't see the other tail. Hahaha. Good one.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy2Goons: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assuming $|x| > 1$, we have that

$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n} < \bigg(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\bigg)^n$$

If $|x| \leqslant 1$, then

$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}\leqslant \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}$$

is a monotone sequence of continuous functions which converges to $0$ on $[-1,1]$ which is compact. Apply Dini's theorem to this case.

Answer (score 0):

You know this converges to 0 uniformly and it is positive, so take the derivative and find the maximum.  This maximum converges to 0 which proves the point because it will be less than $1/(n-1)^2$ which is your $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x| < \sqrt {\epsilon}$ we have $|f_n(x)| <\epsilon$. For $|x| \geq \sqrt {\epsilon}$ note that $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac 1 {{(1+\epsilon)}^{n-1}}$.